# Reading txt results 0, but has entries

Tags: python, file

strange problem and I can't find the issue. The following code copies filtered entries into a new txt and should print the number of entries, that the only_iphone.txt file contains (in lines) in the end.

The result is always 0. When I open the txt, however, it contains entries.

Am I missing something?

```html
term = "iphone"
file = open(./export/importlist.txt')
extoutput = open('./export/only_iphone.txt', 'w')
for line in file:
    line.strip().split(',')
    if term in line and 'samsung' not in line and 'htc' not in line:
        #print line
        extoutput.write('{}'.format(line))
file.close()
time.sleep(1)


numberofentries = 0

with open('./export/only_iphone.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            numberofentries += 1

    print (numberofentries)
```

Comment: You mean `line = line.strip().split(',')`

Comment: Also the `if line.strip()` check is pretty strange. What exactly are you trying to do there? _Strip returns a copy of the string with leading and trailing characters removed. If chars is omitted or None, whitespace characters are removed._ But you are not saving it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close your extoutput file

```
term = "iphone"
file = open('./export/importlist.txt')
extoutput = open('./export/only_iphone.txt', 'w')
for line in file:
    line = line.strip().split(',')
    if term in line and 'samsung' not in line and 'htc' not in line:
        #print line
        extoutput.write('{}'.format(line))
file.close()
extoutput.close()

time.sleep(1)


numberofentries = 0

with open('./export/only_iphone.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            numberofentries += 1

    print (numberofentries)
```

Comment: Oh my god. Facepalm! Blush! Thanks for that, Gabriel!

Answer (score 1):

To continue on Gabriel's answer, it's better practice to use the `with open` way of opening a file. so you cannot forget to close it, like you did in the second part of your code.

```
term = "iphone"
with open('./export/importlist.txt') as my_file:
    with open('./export/only_iphone.txt', 'w') as extoutput:
        for line in my_file:
            line = line.strip().split(',')
            if term in line and 'samsung' not in line and 'htc' not in line:
                #print line
                extoutput.write('{}'.format(line))

time.sleep(1)


numberofentries = 0

with open('./export/only_iphone.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            numberofentries += 1

    print (numberofentries)
```

Comment: That's right. That is a better way to go. I always try to use with open, but in this case - I was unsure how to achieve it with two files. Looks pretty straight forward. Thanks for that!